# Can't return / get access to a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, geolocation, return

I have the following lines of code. Everything works except for setting the variable "UserLocation" and printing it to the console. My goal is to get the coordinates I find in the showPosition() function as a global variable that can be accessed anywhere, because I will be using them a lot and for many purposes.

What am I missing here? I've tried setting the coordinates variable inside showPosition to a global variable, tried returning the variable, etc. The only way I can get those coordinates out of that function as of now is to pass it as a parameter to a whole other function which I don't want to do.

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var UserLocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    console.log(UserLocation); // This doesn't work and gives me "undefined"
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    var coordinates = new Array();
    coordinates.push(Math.floor(position.coords.latitude));
    coordinates.push(Math.floor(position.coords.longitude));
    console.log(coordinates) // This works
    return coordinates;
  }
```

Comment: This happens because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` accepts a success callback that will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: To achieve what you're looking for, you may declare **UserLocation** variable on global scope and set its value inside **showPosition** function. Still, be aware that at the time console.log is called, **showPosition** function may still have not been executed, and so **UserLocation** may still not have a value assigned to it. If you wan't to log **UserLocation**, you may do it after assigning a value to it inside **showPosition**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous.  As indicated in the comments, this means that `UserLocation` will be undefined until `getCurrentPosition` has completed.

Promises are excellent for dealing with asynchronous code.  The following uses ECMA6 promises to set your global variable:

```
function getUserLocation() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve);
      } else {
        reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
      }
  });
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var coordinates = new Array();
    coordinates.push(Math.floor(position.coords.latitude));
    coordinates.push(Math.floor(position.coords.longitude));
    console.log(coordinates) // This works
    return coordinates;
}

function setGlobalCoordsAndAlert(coordinates) {
    window.coordinates = coordinates;
    alert(coordinates);
}

getUserLocation()
  .then(showPosition)
  .then(setGlobalCoordsAndAlert)
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

ECMA6 promises aren't available in older browsers, so check out a polyfill if you're worried about compatibility.

- [Promise documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Promise polyfill.](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

Comment: Thanks for your very clear answer. You actually also helped clear out problems I was having with another project. Awesome help.