# Javascript understanding callback functions and execution

Tags: javascript, callback

I have `script1` and `script2`. Here is some code from `script1`:

```
var pos;

function foo(param){pos = param;}

bar(foo);
```

Now in `script2`:

```
function bar(callback){
    //prints 'function'
    console.log(typeof callback);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        success,
        fail
    );
}

function success(position, callback){
    //prints 'undefined'
    console.log(typeof callback);
    var pos= {
        lat: position.coords.latitude, 
        long: position.coords.longitude
    };
    callback(pos);
}
```

How do I correctly pass `foo` as a callback function to `bar`, and chain it to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`? How can I correctly get `pos` back to `script1`? Why can't I just return the values instead??

Comment: How is `success` being called?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Due to the asynchronous behavior of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, I recommend using promises for what you're after.  Here's an answer I submitted for this use case, earlier today: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287407/cant-return-get-access-to-a-variable-inside-a-function/38287844#38287844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-pass the callback to the success function

```
function bar(callback){
    //prints 'function'
    console.log(typeof callback);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(pos){
            // repass callback to success method
            success(pos, callback);
        },
        fail
    );
}
```

Comment: this works, but as someone from a Java background, i just don't understand - even though i know that functions are objects in javascript

Comment: getCurrentPostion(success, fail) passes two function pointers to invoke async and those methods don't know anything about the scope where it is invoked - same applies to Java.    in parameters are private scope - just like Java

Answer (score 0):

```
var pos;

function foo(param){pos=param; console.log(param);}

bar(foo);

function bar(callback){
    //prints 'function'
    //console.log(callback);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         success.bind(null, callback), 
        fail
    );

}

function success(callback, position){
    //prints 'function'

    var pos= {
        lat: position.coords.latitude, 
        long: position.coords.longitude
    };

   callback(pos);
}

function fail(){
  console.log('failed');
}
```